# How to Group array items elements are using object distinct to item ,value using jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

### I am trying to group my array by Id in jQuery, the details of my code and what I am trying to achieve.

My array is something like this:

```
var array = [
    {id:1, value:1}, 
    {id:1, value:2},
    {id:1, value:3},
    {id:2, value:4},
    {id:2, value:5},
    {id:2, value:6}, 
    {id:3, value:7},
    {id:3, value:8},
    {id:3, value:1},
    {id:4, value:2},
    {id:4, value:3},
    {id:4, value:4},
    {id:6, value:5},
    {id:6, value:1},
    {id:6, value:2},
    {id:12, value:3},
    {id:12, value:4},
    {id:12, value:5},
    {id:1, value:"a"},
    {id:1, value:"b"},
    {id:1, value:"c"},
    {id:2, value:4},
    {id:2, value:5},
];
```

---

desired result should be

```
var output = [
{
id:1,
group:[
    {value:1}, 
    {value:2},
    {value:3},
  ]
},
{
id:2,
group:[
    {value:4},
    {value:5},
    {value:6},
  ]
},
  {
id:3,
group:[
    {value:7},
    {value:8},
    {value:1},
  ]
},
{
id:4,
group:[
    {value:2},
    {value:3},
    {value:4},
  ]
},
{
id:6,
group:[
    {value:5},
    {value:1},
    {value:2},
  ]
},
{
id:12,
group:[
    {value:3},
    {value:4},
    {value:5},
  ]
},
{
id:1,
group:[
    {value:a},
    {value:b},
    {value:c},
  ]
}
{
id:2,
group:[
    {value:4},
    {value:5} 
   ]
}
];
```

---

Is there a helpful script for this, or should I stick to using js, and then looping through the resulting object to do the myself?

I'm trying:

```
var array1 = [
    {id:1, value:1}, 
    {id:1, value:2},
    {id:1, value:3},
    {id:2, value:4},
    {id:2, value:5},
    {id:2, value:6}, 
    {id:3, value:7},
    {id:3, value:8},
    {id:3, value:1},
    {id:4, value:2},
    {id:4, value:3},
    {id:4, value:4},
    {id:6, value:5},
    {id:6, value:1},
    {id:6, value:2},
    {id:12, value:3},
    {id:12, value:4},
    {id:12, value:5},
    {id:1, value:"a"},
    {id:1, value:"b"},
    {id:1, value:"c"},
    {id:2, value:4},
    {id:2, value:5},
];


var FinalArray=[];
for(i=0;i<array1.length;i++)
{ 
    var newArray={id:array1[i].id,group:{value:[]}};
    var group={value:[]};
    newArray.group=group;

    if(newArray.id == array1[i].id){
        for(j=i;j<array1.length;j++)
        {
            if(array1[i].id==array1[j].id)
            {
                group.value.push(array1[j].value);
            }   
        }
    }

    var IsAddeble=true;

    if(FinalArray.length>0)
    {
        for(k=0;k<FinalArray.length;k++)
        {
            if(FinalArray[FinalArray.length-1].id==array1[i].id)
            {
                IsAddeble=false;
            } 
        }    
    }
    if(IsAddeble){  
        FinalArray.push(newArray);
    }
}
console.log(FinalArray);
```

### Any solution how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the last item of the result array and insert a new object in `group` or create a new group object.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, value: 1 }, { id: 1, value: 2 }, { id: 1, value: 3 }, { id: 2, value: 4 }, { id: 2, value: 5 }, { id: 2, value: 6 }, { id: 3, value: 7 }, { id: 3, value: 8 }, { id: 3, value: 1 }, { id: 4, value: 2 }, { id: 4, value: 3 }, { id: 4, value: 4 }, { id: 6, value: 5 }, { id: 6, value: 1 }, { id: 6, value: 2 }, { id: 12, value: 3 }, { id: 12, value: 4 }, { id: 12, value: 5 }, { id: 1, value: "a" }, { id: 1, value: "b" }, { id: 1, value: "c" }, { id: 2, value: 4 }, { id: 2, value: 5 }],
    result = array.reduce((r, { id, value }) => {
        var last = r[r.length - 1];
        if (last && last.id === id) {
            last.group.push({ value });
        } else {
            r.push({ id, group: [{ value }] });
        }
        return r;
    }, [])

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for help,but  somthing wrong  its group type but not  correct i want every elment id check if id is same push array object or not id same create new object same as id

Comment: i want this type :

Answer (score 1):

Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var array = [
    {id:1, value:1}, 
    {id:1, value:2},
    {id:1, value:3},
    {id:2, value:4},
    {id:2, value:5},
    {id:2, value:6}, 
    {id:3, value:7},
    {id:3, value:8},
    {id:3, value:1},
    {id:4, value:2},
    {id:4, value:3},
    {id:4, value:4},
    {id:6, value:5},
    {id:6, value:1},
    {id:6, value:2},
    {id:12, value:3},
    {id:12, value:4},
    {id:12, value:5},
    {id:1, value:"a"},
    {id:1, value:"b"},
    {id:1, value:"c"},
    {id:2, value:4},
    {id:2, value:5},
];


var match;

var output = array.reduce( function(arr,obj){
 
 match=0;
  
 for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
 {

  if(arr[i].id==obj.id)
  {
   arr[i].group.push({value:obj.value});
   match=1;
  }
 }
 
 if(!match)
 {
   arr.push({id:obj.id,group:[{value:obj.value}]});
 }

 return arr;
},[]
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(output,null, 2)); // spacing level = 2
```